# Generalized Eigenspace Problem

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a problem from Hoffman and Kunze. We are allowed to assume the primary decomposition theorem:

Suppose the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $f=(x-c_1)^{d_1}...(x-c_m)^{d_m}$ and the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $p=(x-c_1)^{j_1}...(x-c_m)^{j_m}$. Prove the following:

$N(T-c_i)^{j_i}=S=\{\alpha\in V:(T-c_iI)^m\alpha=0 \ \text{for some} \ m\}$

My attempt: For 1) Clearly $N(T-c_i)^{j_i}\subseteq S$ (by letting $m=j_i$). Now let $\alpha\in S$ so $\exists m$ such that $(T-c_iI)^m\alpha=0$. If $m\leq j_i$, it's clear that $\alpha\in N(T-c_iI)^{j_i}$. Now suppose $m>j_i$. I'm not sure what to do from here, but I think we use the fact that the primary decomposition theorem $\implies$ the minimal polynomial of $T$ restricted to $N(T-c_iI)^{j_i}$ is $(x-c_i)^{j_i}$.

Does anyone know how to proceed from here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the primary decomposition theorem, the space $X$ can be written as a direct sum of the generalized  eigenspaces of $T$ (each corresponding to distinct eigenvalues).  It follows that no two generalized eigenspaces intersect.

For your problem, it is clear that the statement holds for $ j_i \geq m$. To show that it holds for $m > j_i$, we want to show that
$$N(T-c_i I)^{j_i} = N (T-c_i I)^m, \forall m > j_i .$$

Assume not.  Then there is a $v \neq 0$ such that 
$$(T-c_i I)^{j_i +k}v=0,\: and\: (T-c_i I)^{j_i} v \neq 0 .$$
The minimal polynomial $p$  is the lowest-degree polynomial for which $p(T) = 0$. So multiply $(T-c_i I)^{j_i} v \neq 0$  by 
$$\small { (T-c_1I)^{j_1}...(T-c_{i-1}I)^{j_{i-1}}(T-c_{i+1}I)^{j_{i+1}}...(T-c_{r}I)^{j_{r}}} $$

This is $p(T)$, hence is $0$.  But, since $(T-c_i I)^{j_i} v$ is not zero, but is now sent to zero, it is therefore a generalized eigenvector of some other eigenvalue that is not $c_i$.  BUT primary decomposition forbids this.  Contradiction.